# PayPal Payments Pro - Declined and Review

Tags: c#, paypal, payment

i'm trying to get PayPal Payments Pro to work using this code

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        // Create the HttpContent for the form to be posted.
        var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("USER", PPLUser),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("VENDOR", PPLVendor),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PARTNER", PPLPartner),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PWD", PPLPwd),            
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TENDER", "C"), // D=Pinless debit; C=Credit Card (REQ)
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TRXTYPE", "S"), //Sale(REQ)
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ACCT", this.txtCCNumber.Text),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("EXPDATE", CardExp),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("AMT", txtAmount.Text),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CVV2", txtCVC.Text),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CREDITCARDTYPE", CardTypes.SelectedValue.ToString()),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CURRENCYCODE", "GBP"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("VERSION", "109.0"),
        });

        // Get the response.
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com", requestContent);
            // Get the response content.
            HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

            // Get the stream of the content.
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
            {
                // Write the output.
                Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
            }
```

But this is the response i get:

```
RESULT=12&PNREF=A70A9BC2A5B9&RESPMSG=Declined&PREFPSMSG=Review: More than one rule was triggered for Review
```

Am I missing a header or something obvious?
Strangely the same code appears to work fine if I use a different vendor/partner/password
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi ItsDanny- sounds like you have fraud protection filters deployed in the manager account. The review by 'rule trigger' denotes a filter of some sort that's set.

Comment: Hi, yes it was all to do with Fraud settings, as well as transaction limits. I can't set your reply as the answer though, as it's a comment.

Comment: no problem at all bud, just glad you got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you got the fraud review fixed. For test credit cards just go [HERE](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm). If you have an issue with those cards, I doubt you will hop over to this [SITE](http://ccaples.com/index.php/misc/tools-and-stuff/cc-num-gen) and use them. Note: even though they state 'Payflow' cards only, you can use the others; doesn't matter. 8^)

Lastly, the exp date on cards are anytime in the future; IE- July 2nd 2016; today is 7/1/16 and the CSC or CVV is 123 on all test cards posted to our servers. Do not use the 4 and 15 1's when testing as that error's out periodically.

Let me know if that works for you. Have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a problem with the code. It seems the card or account you used was declined by Paypal and set for review. PayPal has extensive anti-fraud procedures. Get in touch with customer service to see why it was declined.

Comment: Hi, I'm in Sandbox/Piliot mode. Is there a list of current test cards i can use? I've checked some settings in the Manager but, who knows if it's right or wrong. There is an obscene amount of info on this so it's a bit tricky to know whether you're doing the right thing/in the right place or not!

Comment: I haven't used PayPal sandbox in a while but I distinctly remember them having test credit card numbers. I will take a look through some old code to see if I can dig something up. Otherwise it should be in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Michael but i'm sorted, all to do with settings. Thanks anyway.